# moving circles together in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I have been working on this project for too long. I am clueless at this point. I am a complete noobie at python. i just started learning python, and im supposed to make a drawing. I just want to give up at this point, since basically nobody wants to help me. This is what the project is actually supposed to look like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

listCircleColors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'yellow', 'purple', 'white']

intGroup = 5
angleLeft = 360 / (intGroup * len(listCircleColors))

def moveAndDraw(turtle):
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(15)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.circle(100)

def moveSameColorCircle():
    for color in listCircleColors:
        for _ in range(12):
            for turtle in listCircleObjects:
                if turtle.pencolor() == color:
                    turtle.undo()
                    moveAndDraw(turtle)

            screen.update()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(900, 900)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.tracer(False)

headAngle = 0
listCircleObjects = list()

for _ in range(intGroup):
    for color in listCircleColors:
         turtle = Turtle()
        turtle.hideturtle()
        turtle.setheading(headAngle)
        turtle.color(color)
        turtle.pensize(2)
        turtle.circle(100)
     headAngle += angleLeft

    listCircleObjects.append(turtle)

screen.update()

screen.ontimer(moveSameColorCircle, 500)
screen.exitonclick()
```

basically, im supposed to draw a spirograph and then move them towards the sides of the screen by its color, but in a group, beginning by moving all the red circles to the sides of the screen, then green, then blue, etc. I want to do the exact same thing, but using pygame. So far, i am able to draw a the spirograph and move it, just not one color group at a time, but the whole spirograph moving to the right. I've read so many stack overflow posts about moving multiple objects and creating different screens, but i still cant seem to figure out how to move the circles by its color group. This is my current code:

```
import pygame
import math
import sys
import time
#setting colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255,  0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 127, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
PURPLE = (160, 32, 240)
#setting what order the colors go in
listCircleColor = (RED, BLUE, GREEN, ORANGE, YELLOW, PURPLE, WHITE)
#how many circles per color
intGroup = 5
#the space between each circle
turnangle = 360/35
#width of screen
width = 600
#height of screen
height = 600
#radius of circles
radius = 100
#making the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
#if the code is running, then continue
running = True
##.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, (0, 0), radius, width=2)
circles = []
circles_rect = []
#draw

#draw
alpha = turnangle
for i in range(intGroup):
    for cl in listCircleColor:
        surfacetemp = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        surfacetemp = surfacetemp.convert_alpha()
        surfacetemp.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))

        ##circlerect = pygame.rect
    if alpha > 0 and alpha < 90:
        circlerect = pygame.draw.circle(surfacetemp, cl, (300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(alpha)), 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(alpha))), radius, width=2)
        # second quarter of circles
    if alpha > 90 and alpha < 180:
        circlerect = pygame.draw.circle(surfacetemp, cl, (300 - radius * math.cos(math.radians(180 - alpha)), 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(180 - alpha))), radius, width=2)
        # third quarter of circles
    if alpha > 180 and alpha < 270:
        circlerect = pygame.draw.circle(surfacetemp, cl, (300 - radius * math.cos(math.radians(270 - alpha)), 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(270 - alpha))), radius, width=2)
        # last quarter of circles
    if alpha > 270 and alpha < 360:
        circlerect = pygame.draw.circle(surfacetemp, cl, (300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(360 - alpha)), 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(360 - alpha))), radius, width=2)

    alpha = alpha + turnangle
    ##circles.append(circlerect)
    circles.append(surfacetemp)
    circles_rect.append(surfacetemp.get_rect())

# move"

#exit only when user clicks on exit button
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False


    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for crect, ret in zip(circles, circles_rect):
        ret.right += 5
        ret.left += 5
        screen.blit(crect, ret)


pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(20)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

also, for some reason, when i run this code, nothing appears, only a dark screen. I dont know what i did wrong, but before writing this i made sure that everything was working. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The display needs to be updated in the application loop:

```py
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False


    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for crect, ret in zip(circles, circles_rect):
        ret.right += 5
        ret.left += 5
        screen.blit(crect, ret)

# INDENTATION
#-->|

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(20)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

If you draw on the *Surface* associated to the PyGame display, this is not immediately visible in the display. The changes become visibel, when the display is updated with either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip).

---

Complete and tested code:

```py
import pygame
import math
import sys
import time
#setting colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255,  0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
ORANGE = (255, 127, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
PURPLE = (160, 32, 240)
#setting what order the colors go in
listCircleColor = (RED, BLUE, GREEN, ORANGE, YELLOW, PURPLE, WHITE)
#how many circles per color
intGroup = 5
#the space between each circle
turnangle = 360/35
#width of screen
width = 600
#height of screen
height = 600
#radius of circles
radius = 100
#making the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
#if the code is running, then continue
running = True
##.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, (0, 0), radius, width=2)
circles = []
circles_rect = []
#draw

#draw
alpha = turnangle
for i in range(intGroup):
    for cl in listCircleColor:
        surfacetemp = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        surfacetemp = surfacetemp.convert_alpha()
        surfacetemp.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))

        ##circlerect = pygame.rect
    if alpha > 0 and alpha < 90:
        circlerect = pygame.draw.circle(surfacetemp, cl, (300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(alpha)), 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(alpha))), radius, width=2)
        # second quarter of circles
    if alpha > 90 and alpha < 180:
        circlerect = pygame.draw.circle(surfacetemp, cl, (300 - radius * math.cos(math.radians(180 - alpha)), 300 + radius * math.sin(math.radians(180 - alpha))), radius, width=2)
        # third quarter of circles
    if alpha > 180 and alpha < 270:
        circlerect = pygame.draw.circle(surfacetemp, cl, (300 - radius * math.cos(math.radians(270 - alpha)), 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(270 - alpha))), radius, width=2)
        # last quarter of circles
    if alpha > 270 and alpha < 360:
        circlerect = pygame.draw.circle(surfacetemp, cl, (300 + radius * math.cos(math.radians(360 - alpha)), 300 - radius * math.sin(math.radians(360 - alpha))), radius, width=2)

    alpha = alpha + turnangle
    ##circles.append(circlerect)
    circles.append(surfacetemp)
    circles_rect.append(surfacetemp.get_rect())

# move"

#exit only when user clicks on exit button
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False


    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for crect, ret in zip(circles, circles_rect):
        ret.right += 5
        ret.left += 5
        screen.blit(crect, ret)


    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(20)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: I made a new question because this one got closed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70599217/is-it-possible-to-move-an-object-diagonally-in-pygame

Answer (score 0):

In order to display the changes made to the screen, add `pygame.display.flip()` to the end of your game loop.
Changes are only displayed after you flip.
[Further documentation here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Comment: okay, i added it, but i still get a black screen when i run it